# Keycloak - Event Listener provider not firing new realm creation event

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have implemented a custom Event Listener provider.

I'm able to receive all the events except the **realm creation event** (new realm creation). I would like to get the event during realm creation as well.

Is this supported by Keycloak ? If not, any other possibilities to achieve this ?

I'm using Keycloak version 4.5.0.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research on keycloak code, I came to conclusion that keycloak is not providing that event by default.

So I modified below files from keycloak which will help to capture Realm creation and deletion events.

**Change 1 (Most Important) :**

File:

> keycloak/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/managers/RealmManager.java

Function:

> protected void setupRealmDefaults

In above function you should add your event listener to the realm during realm creation.

```
Set<String> eventListenerSet = new HashSet<>();
eventListenerSet.add("jboss-logging"); //This listener will be there by default
eventListenerSet.add("EVENT_LISTENER_YOU_WANT_TO_RECEIVE_EVENT");
realm.setEventsListeners(eventListenerSet);
```

**Change 2 :**

File:

> keycloak/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/RealmsAdminResource.java

Function:

> public Response importRealm

In above function add below lines before returning response

```
Line 1: Create object for admin event
Line 2: Prepare event to trigger with appropriate event type and representation, in this case Create
AdminEventBuilder adminEvent = new AdminEventBuilder(realm, auth, session, clientConnection); 

adminEvent.operation(OperationType.CREATE).resource(ResourceType.REALM).representation(StripSecretsUtils.strip(rep)).success();
```

**Change 3 (Needed only if delete event is required)**

File:

> keycloak/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/RealmAdminResource.java

Function:

> public void deleteRealm

Add the below code after the First Line

```
AdminAuth adminAuth = auth.adminAuth();
RealmRepresentation realmRepresentation = new RealmRepresentation();
realmRepresentation.setRealm(realm.getName());
AdminEventBuilder adminEvent = new AdminEventBuilder(realm, adminAuth, session, connection);
adminEvent.operation(OperationType.DELETE).resource(ResourceType.REALM).representation(realmRepresentation).success();
```

Comment: There is a reason to keycloak developers does not implement this feature ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but seems like they don't have such use case or this use case is out of scope in keycloak point of view. As far as I gone through the code there is no security issue or something like that with this implementation.